# What is your idea about this conjecture?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, divisibility, analytic-number-theory

I conjecture that in a consecutive sequence of $n$ natural numbers all greater than $n$, there exists at least one number which is not divisible by any prime number less than or equal to $n/2$.

Can any one prove or disprove this?

Comment: If it is a prime then obviously it cannot be divisible by any prime whatsoever.

Comment: @KprimeX right.  So if there is a prime in the string, the conjecture is true.  Possibly, though, there is a non-prime in the string which works...the conjecture is good either way.

Comment: This depends on the sum ${1\over2}+{1\over3}+...+{1\over p}-{1\over 2\cdot3}-{1\over 2\cdot 5}-...-{1\over 2\cdot p}-{1\over 3\cdot5}-...+{1\over 2\cdot3\cdot5}+...$ and so on. If this sum approaches infinity then I think your conjecture is false but we need really a lot of primes to find a counter-example. If this sum is always less than one then your conjecture is true. Maybe some smart people may somehow show this sum is less than one.

Comment: @cr001 $1-$ your sum is equal to $(1-\frac 1 2)(1-\frac 1 3)(1-\frac 1 5)\cdots (1-\frac 1 p)$

Comment: How does my conjecture depend on this sum?

Comment: @Dylan But ${1\over2}+{1\over3}-{1\over6}={2\over3}$ while $(1-{1\over2})(1-{1\over3})={1\over3}$ so they are not equal I guess.

Comment: @some one Multiply it by $2n$ then it basically counts the number of numbers divisible by $1,2,3,...,p$. If it approaches infinity there would possibly be a counter-example. However actually $2n$ approaches infinity as well so in fact you need to compare their rate of approaching infinity...

Comment: @Dylan Actually it is equal to $1-$your formula. I guess one may use it as a hint.

Comment: Hmm, it seems the formula is indeed less than one since it is $1-(1-\frac 1 2)(1-\frac 1 3)(1-\frac 1 5)\cdots (1-\frac 1 p)$. This means woughly speaking. with $2n$ consecutive numbers there would be less than $2n$ numbers which is a multiple of primes $1,2,...,p$ so the conjecture is likely to be true however one needs to deal with the rounding issues as we are dealing with integers. I will think about this when I have time.

Comment: I see that the $1-$ at the start of my comment hid itself away :P

Comment: @cr001: I think the sum solves nothing. If the sequence is n+k,n+k+1,...,2n-1+k (k>=1) , then the sum is [(2n-1+k)/2]-[(n+k-1)/2]+[(2n-1+k)/3]-[(n+k-1)/3]+.... , then the question is whether the sum is less than n or not

Comment: In an answer to a  post ”Bertand and Mersenne” a user be the name of “quid” mentioned that for every $ϵ>0$ there exists a Cϵ such that there is a prime between n and (1+ϵ)n for every $n≥Cϵ$. 
The conjecture seems related to this.

Comment: By the way: before you posted this, did you do any numerical work to test your conjecture up to some $N$?

Comment: @SimonS: Good question either way,  but the numerical work in this case might be misleading. Suppose it is true for some but not all n?

Answer (score 7):

The conjecture is false. This problem is directly related to finding large gaps between primes, and the methods of Erdos, Rankin and others.

Define the *Jacobsthal function* $j(q)$ to be the largest gap between consecutive reduced residues modulo $q$, that is the largest gap between elements that are relatively prime to $q$. Note that your conjecture is equivalent to asking if  $$j\left(\prod_{p\leq n/2} p\right)\leq n$$ holds for all $n$. To see why, consider any sequence of $n$ consecutive numbers modulo $M=\prod_{p\leq n/2}p$. Then each of them will be divisible by some  $p\leq n/2$ if and only if $j\left(\prod_{p\leq n/2}p\right)\geq n$.

This function $j$ is directly related to best lower bounds for prime gaps. Indeed, if $$j\left(\prod_{p\leq X}p\right)\geq f(X)$$ infinitely often, (where $f$ is a nice function, strictly increasing etc.) then $$\max_{p_{n+1}\leq x} p_{n+1}-p_n \geq f(\log x).$$  In a recent paper of [Kevin Ford, Ben Green, Sergei Konyagin, James Maynard, Terence Tao](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1412.5029v2.pdf), they proved that $$j\left(\prod_{p\leq x} p\right)\gg \frac{x\log x \log \log \log x}{\log \log x},$$ and hence

$$\max_{p_n\leq X} p_{n+1}-p_n\gg \frac{\log X\log \log X \log \log  \log \log X}{\log \log \log X}.$$
We remark that Erdos had put a $10000\$$ prize on this result, the largest amount he set for any problem.

While this result does disprove your conjecture, we do not need use such powerful theorems. We need only use Lemma 7.13 of Montgomery and Vaughn which states that $$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{j\left(\prod_{p\leq n} p\right)}{n}=\infty.$$ This is proven using an elementary sieving argument, and the result was originally given by Westzynthius.

Comment: You got me for 5 seconds!

Comment: Wow this problem was so much harder than I thought. Thanks for writing up the answer.

Comment: Well yes, it is true for *some* $n$. Based on the results calculated in this paper: http://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/2009-78-266/S0025-5718-08-02166-2/S0025-5718-08-02166-2.pdf I think that the smallest counterexample occurs for $n=86$. I don't know what the actual sequence of $86$ numbers is that are all divisible by primes at most $43$ though, and I haven't read enough of the paper to see if they suggest a practical method for calculating what the sequence is. I just know that the naive approach will take the computer that I am working on more than a year to compute the sequence.

Comment: As for how much of the paper I have read: the relevant table of results to find what the minimal $n$ is is at the top of page 2, so I stopped there.

Comment: @Dylan: Using Eric N's reformulation my claim is $j(2\cdot 3\cdot...\cdot13)\leq 30.$ In the table in the paper $n$ is the *index* of the largest prime. If $n=6$ then $h(n)$ is 22. According to this paper my claim is true, but the paper gives a stronger result.

Answer (score 0):

The conjecture is false.
We can cover $O(n^2)$ natural numbers using the primes not exceeding $n$.
Check the [Jacobsthal function](http://oeis.org/wiki/Jacobsthal_function.)

Comment: To disprove the OP's conjecture you need to quote the lower bounds for $j(n)$ and the fact that $\limsup_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{j(n)}{\log n}>2$ Iwaniec's result goes the opposite direction, showing that there exists a constant $C$ such that any interval of length $Cn^2$ has an integer not divisible by any prime less than $n/2$.